# Cross compiling Linux wifi driver

Tags: c, linux, arm, cross-compiling, openembedded

I'm trying to cross-compile a Realtek wifi driver for an Airlink AWLL6075 wireless n usb adapter. The chipset is apparently RTL8191SU, and I've obtained the drive for Linux from the Realtek download site.
When cross-compiling for the ARM Linux with OpenEmbedded, the compilation fails with the following messages:

```
os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c: In function 'rtw_os_indicate_scan_done':
os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c:222:34: error: implicit declaration of function 'wdev_priv'
```

The offending section from mlme_linux.c is:

```
extern void indicate_wx_scan_complete_event(_adapter *padapter);
void rtw_os_indicate_scan_done( _adapter *padapter, bool aborted)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211
    rtw_cfg80211_indicate_scan_done(wdev_to_priv(padapter->rtw_wdev), aborted);
#endif //CONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211
    indicate_wx_scan_complete_event(padapter);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: BTW: `wdev_to_priv(...)` is defined in include/ioctl_cfg80211.h like this: `#define wdev_to_priv(w) (struct rtw_wdev_priv *)(wdev_priv(w))`.

Comment: is this driver in c or c++? I added a c tag based on the extension of the mlme_Linux file, but I'd just like to confirm.

Comment: It's in C. Here's a link to the [Realtek driver download](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit declaration of function means that the compiler can't find the function declaration in the header.

Try and track down the header file containing this guy. Perhaps dependency is missing.

A quick google gives out cfg80211.h as the culprit. Found in http://www.takatan.net/lxr/ident?i=wdev_priv

Searching for cfg80211 gives 
http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/developers/Documentation/cfg80211

As far as I can see, all you need to do is download the cfg80211.h file from the first link and include in your project.

Comment: Hmm, okay, it looks like the kernel source I have (2.6.28) has a different version of that header file, which doesn't have the definition for this function.